# Delete pointer to std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I have a function like this:

```
void cb( void *obj )
{
    if(nullptr != obj)
    {
        auto f = static_cast< function<void()>* >(obj);
        (*f)();
    }
}
```

and I use it this way:

```
auto obj = new function<void()> ( bind(&AClass::AMethod, &x) );
cb(obj);
```

where AClass is a class, AMethod is a method of AClass and x is an instance of AClass.

Now the question is: why deleting the pointer to std::function inside cb makes the program crash:

```
void cb( void *o )
{
    if(nullptr != o)
    {
        auto f = static_cast< function<void()>* >(o);
        (*f)();
        delete f; // <===
    }
}
```

whilst deleting it after the call to cb does not?

```
auto obj = new function<void()> ( bind(&AClass::AMethod, &x) );
cb(obj);
delete obj; // <===
```

Comment: Probably because of other errors in your code that we can't see...?

Comment: Stop using `new`, stop using `void*` and (when you really must use `new`) stop using dumb pointers. There are no obvious errors here but, with all this error-prone craziness going on, there will almost certainly be something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Voted to close "off-topic", because that's the reason that includes "questions about your failing programs must include code that reproduces the problem", and this code doesn't reproduce the problem. What I really wanted to do was close "no longer relevant", or possibly "this question contains a false assumption and cannot be answered" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine on both **g++ 4.8.1** and **clang 3.4**. Also both show nothing of interest **valgrind**. So maybe the problem is somewhere else in your code or related to your compiler version?

I tested deleteing at both of the mentioned places.

Comment: You are right. I just spent the last hour stumbling on this, and now I see that the error is elsewhere... thank you anyway.